# Datatype mismatch error when submitting data

Tags: java

I have one Jframe with 8 JComboboxes and textfield...when i pressed submit button got Datatype mismatch error

```
try
                {


                     String Query="replace into enquiry (`Enquiry No`,`Client`,`User`,`Purchase`,`Sales`,"
                            + "`Date`,`Technical Data`,"
                            + "`Product`,`Remarks`,`Amount`,`Userboss`,`PurchaserBoss`,`SalesBoss`,`month`,`Pagency`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                    PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(Query);

                    pst.setString(1, textField.getText());
                    String c=client.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(2, c);
                    String u=user.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(3, u);
                    String p=purchase.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(4,p);
                    String se=sengg.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(5, se);
                    pst.setString(6, ed.getText());
                    pst.setString(7, td.getText());
                    String pd=prod.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(8, pd);
                    pst.setString(9, remark.getText());
                    pst.setString(10, amt.getText());
                    String ub=uboss.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(11, ub);
                    String pb=pboss.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(12, pb);
                    String sb=sboss.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(13, sb);
                    pst.setString(14, qmonth.getText());
                    String pa1=pa.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    pst.setString(15, pa1);
                    pst.execute();


                }
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: on which line you get the error?

Comment: post stack trace

Comment: i guess the columns `Date`,`Technical Data` are date columns, so you have to set Dates here not Strings

Comment: @Tushar sir, pst.execute();

Comment: @Jens.. pst.setString(6, ed.getText());..is for date..and here I set today's date in another method..here just want to submit this in table

Comment: Well, the error tell you that you pass a `String` to the field `Technical Data` using `setString` but this is a `Date` so you new to pass a `Date` instance with `setDate`

Comment: @G.S For that you have to use `setDate()` and not `setString()`

Comment: public void showDate()
 {
  Calendar c=new GregorianCalendar();
  int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  ed.setText(+day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
 }................................I used this for today's date

Comment: I tried setDate() but it gives error...

Comment: @G.S see the edit about your comment. you don't need to create the String if you simply want the current Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `String` to a `Date` column using [`PreparedStatement.setString(int index, String x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)).

You have a [`PreparedStatement.setDate(int index, java.sql.Date date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)) method for Date column.

Simply parse the String you have and pass this `java.util.Date` instance to the method.

PS : `java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`.

EDIT : 
In a comment, you said you simply get the current Date with `new GregorianCalendar()` to build the String. So you can simply pass `new Date()` to get the current date.

[`java.util.Date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date())

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.